# Como superponer 2 div en html

Tags: html, css, div

https://github.com/felipedelosh/ecomerceFuneraria

Estoy haciendo una pagina HTML+CSS con boostrap, la cosa es que tengo una imagen de fondo y un formulario:

```
<!--Form-->
            <div class="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <iframe class="googleFrom" title="Hay que crear este formulario" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScwLJv-lnVavAd3Fc6X4Z9upinv3ud4640wY19J1lEUzVivfA/viewform?embedded=true" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Cargando…</iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="img/barnerProduts.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="imgProdutcsAndIco">
                </div>
            <!--END Form-->
            </div>
```

y yo quiero que se vea asi y no lo consigo, alguien podria ayudarme?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaría que utilices las clases de posicionamiento de Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/, recordando que para que los posicionamientos funcionen, el nodo padre tiene que tener un posicionamiento diferente a static, por eso al div contenedor hay que ponerle position-relative:

```
<div class="form position-relative">
    <div class="row position-absolute col-6 offset-6">
        <iframe class="googleFrom" title="Hay que crear este formulario" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScwLJv-lnVavAd3Fc6X4Z9upinv3ud4640wY19J1lEUzVivfA/viewform?embedded=true" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Cargando…</iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <img src="img/barnerProduts.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="imgProdutcsAndIco">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Bro esa era la respuesta.